# How can I get the time a particular window is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple user survey form in which there is one section where the user needs to click on a link, read the page inside the link and then come back to continue the form. Currently, I have a parent HTML page from which I am providing a link to open a child web page in a different window/tab.

How can I obtain the time the user spent on the child window/tab?

Comment: I sense yet another attempt to force people to read legalise they don't want to read. That's a problem better solved by writing clear, simple, short summaries.

Comment: People will just do something else if there's an annoying timer. If someone wants to read it he will, if not he won't. Don't annoy your users with timers - especially since they are usually too long for osmeone who reads very quickly.

Comment: @Quentin: This is for a user survey for a product that I am building.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: My mistake. I should've mentioned it was for a user survey. I am getting users who are voluntarily agreeing to participate in some user study and they are being compensated for it :)

Answer (score 1):

listen to the user's click by something like

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_time = d.getTime();
    //save in cookie1 
})
```

and now in the other html page where the user is reading....do the same thing but only on window's unload

```
 $(window).unload(function(){
    var d1 = new Date();
    var curr_time1 = d1.getTime();
    //save in cookie2 
})
```

save this also....

then when s/he comes back I mean on its onfocus you can subtract the values of these 2 cookies and divide by 1000 to get seconds as these time will be in milliseconds.

```
 (cookie1 -cookie2)/1000 seconds  //if the cookie thing is used
```

Comment: ohh yes probably...I missed that... then probably cookie is what he is left with

Comment: or a domstorage (and co), if he does need the value only for a script. But I guess a cookie, set after a given timeout to mark an document "read" is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user leave the page by clicking on the link, or is the second page displayed inside the first one? In the first case, you'll have to use a cookie to store the click time, in the second case, use a variable. Time can be retrieved using `new Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Record the time of window open
2. Open the page in a named window
3. Set a timeinteval function (on original page) to check the location.href of the named window of say 1000 ms
4. if changed (to a finished/thankyou page) or not existing user must have finished reading

Answer (score 0):

You should set a cookie or an DOM storage value while the page-to-read is open. In that page:

```
var isFocused = true; // just opened
var secondsLookedupon = 0; // eventually init with a saved value
window.onblur = function(){ isFocused=false; }; // use addEventHandler and co
window.onfocus = function(){ isFocused=true; }; // use addEventHandler and co
window.setInterval(function(){
    if (!isFocused) {
        secondsLookedupon++;
        document.cookie.name = secondsLookedupon; // set a cookie in some way
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("name", secondsLookedupon); // or use DOM storage
    }
}, 1000);
```

and from the survey form page you can read that value from the cookie or domstorage whenever you need.